# Unable to start Jupyter lab or Jupyter notebook in a browser

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I get the following log when starting Jupyter lab or Jupyter notebook-

```
[W 17:03:08.963 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
```

and Jupyter does not start a browser (or a tab in a browser).

(I am using Linux - Manjaro i3 community edition)

I have configured Jupyter to use google-chrome-stable by

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

and setting the following line in `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
```

(Yes I have uncommented the above line)

`/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` and `google-chrome-stable` successfully launch chrome from the terminal.

I have also tried

```
jupyter lab --browser=google-chrome-stable
```

```
jupyter lab --browser google-chrome-stable
```

without success.

Jupyter used to open in a browser when I had Pale Moon installed on my system, but now that I have removed it, I cannot seem to get this working. `google-chrome-stable` is my default browser now.

The obvious workaround is to copy the localhost URL to a web browser but I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: Try `google-chrome` instead of `google-chrome-stable` the former works for me the latter does not. Also, your distro /Chrome version/way of installation (system package manager/flatpak/snap) may be relevant and useful information.

Comment: `google-chrome` does not work for me. `google-chrome-stable` is the package I have installed. I updated the question to state that I am using Manjaro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting dsjamieson's answer [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/unable-to-start-jupyter-lab-or-jupyter-notebook-in-a-browser/1265/8):

You have to give your browser (“google-chrome-stable” in this case) a string format argument (%s) in order to pass it the notebook’s URL:

`jupyter lab --browser="google-chrome-stable %s"`

or, if you prefer opening chrome in app mode:

`jupyter lab --browser="google-chrome-stable --app=%s"`

Answer (score 0):

For Jupyter Lab, to make this more permanent:

`jupyter-lab --generate-config`

Then edit ~/.jupyter/jupyter_lab_config.py and set the ff:

`c.ServerApp.browser = 'google-chrome-stable %s'`

Or do a variation of double0darbo's answer above.